# ERROR in c++ program using Libxml2

Tags: c++, xml

there is my c++ problem, I have error, help me :/

I want to see d:

```
<svg>
    <g>
       <path ***d***="11"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

but my program dont working :/

[how to read a part of xml file in C++ using Libxml2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22994326/how-to-read-a-part-of-xml-file-in-c-using-libxml2/23013398#23013398)

code in my answer, UP

errors :

/home/praktyka/projects/svgreader/main.cpp:83:38: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘const xmlChar* {aka const unsigned char*}’ [-fpermissive]

and

/usr/include/libxml/tree.h:1021:3: error:   initializing argument 2 of ‘xmlChar* xmlGetProp(xmlNodePtr, const xmlChar*)’ [-fpermissive]

Comment: what error do you have?

Comment: Apparently here they have the answer: http://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/137194-using-libxml2-invalid-conversion-const-char*-const-xmlchar*-error.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading from [here](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/137194-using-libxml2-invalid-conversion-const-char%2a-const-xmlchar%2a-error.html) [just googled it]

[`xmlChar`](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlstring.html) seem to be a typedef to `unsigned char`. However a literal string is a const char *... 
So you need to modify your line to be:

```
if(xmlGetProp(cur_node, (const xmlChar *)"d"))
```

To play it really safe (xmlChar is UTF8... your strings might be something different)... consider looking at related functions in libXML2, e.g. [xmlCharStrdup](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlstring.html#xmlCharStrdup)

Comment: ok, thanks compiled but when I want to start program I have "segmentation fault" error

Comment: @user3520459 try running it within a debugger. where the segmentation fault happens?

Comment: I need to using terminal with "cc -o main -I /usr/include/libxml/ main.cpp -lxml2" command and when I start "./main" I have error

Comment: @Rafael not sure what kind of system you have (looks like some kind of unix), check if you have gdb available. Run `gdb ./main` and at gdb prompt: `run`.

Comment: When I use gdb I have "Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400c47 in main ()
"

Comment: you probably have gdb then... [manual for gdb](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/)... If that scares you, you can try GUI front-ends like [ddd](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/)

Comment: @Rafael Couple of things: cur defined in line 11 (`xmlNodePtr      cur;` is not initialized. First time you use it @line 40 (`cur = cur->xmlChildrenNode;`) you're accessing memory over an unitialized pointer (might want to change to: `cur = doc->xmlChildrenNode`... but I'm 100% sure of what you're trying to do). Other thing is that the return to xmlStrcmp is 0, 1 or -1 (equal, greater, lesser).

Comment: oh thanks ;) but now I haven't any error and I havent a d too :/